# Does Using TestFlight With Approved App Trigger New Approval

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, appstore-approval

My app has been approved but is awaiting developer release as I want to release it manually.  Before releasing, it however, I want to test using test flight

When I try to send the approved build to my testers, Apple asks for a login id and then gives me a dialog to Submit For Review.  Is this just Apple being clumsy with their language or do they actually want to review it again before testing even though it's been approved?

Anyone have any experience with this?

Here is pic of dialog box

[image: dialogbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that the Store and TestFlight are two different worlds with two different approval processes — but that the former affects the latter in a peculiar way.

The way the issue you raise has arisen in particular for me is that you release, say, version 1.1 build 26 on the Store, it is ready for sale, and then you proceed with development and upload version 1.1 build 27 to TestFlight. Even though 1.1(26) is being sold already, and even if 1.1(26) was already released on TestFlight, 1.1(27) requires a new approval! In other words, it appears that an App Store release *resets the approval clock*, as it were, on TestFlight.

That is almost exactly your situation. The approval on the App Store apparently means that your next TestFlight upload needs a new approval. So yes, you will have to wait while it is approved. This usually takes just a couple of days.

Comment: Have you ever seen testflight ask for changes or not approve a release already approved for the store?

Comment: I've never seen testflight do _anything_ except approve a submission. But then, I'm pretty conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `TestFlight`, there is even more simpler method to test the Apple approved build (`Pending Developer Release` state) before releasing to Store. It is `Promo code` testing.

You can generate nearly 100 promo codes, if i am not wrong. These promo codes can be shared to the developers so that they can actually test the store build without releasing it to app store.

You can find many articles about Promo codes. I have shared one [here](https://medium.com/uvimate/how-to-generate-and-redeem-ios-app-promo-codes-in-2018-for-the-new-app-store-835d6a1654c1).

Comment: How does this answer the question that was actually asked?